# getting string and data from an URL and showing it in my UI

Tags: java, android

I want to get a simple string from my url. here is my url: 
http://generalbackend.appsazan.com/WeatherAPI.svc/lastUpdate
this return a string just like this : "6/2/2018 2:22:22 PM"
how to get it and show in textview.
any solution?

Comment: What does "how to get it" mean? There should be multiple ways to fetch data, which have you tried and why don't they do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make an HTTP GET call to get this string. You can either use retrofit or volley or a simple HTTPConnection in android

Here is an example code

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
}
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```